# Trying to understand example char_array2.c from "the art of exploitation"

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

OK so I am really trying to understand what's going on this example of "The art of exploitation" second edition. I am trying to see exactly what is going on with the example by closely following the output of GDB on the book. My greatest problem with this is the last part, I included the whole thing so that everyone can see what's going on. Granted I only have very(very) basic knowledge of assembly code. I do understand basic C. 
In the last part the author says that there is a minor difference in the second run of the program from the last one in the address that strcpy() points to and I just can't see it.

The program is simply

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

  char str_a[20];
  strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
  printf(str_a);
  }
```

After I compile it with the necessary options to be able to debug it I load it on
GDB and include the following:

```
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483c4: file char_array2.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy

Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x80483d7: file char_array2.c, line 8.
(gdb)
```

I have no problem with this, it is to my understanding that the
debugger can only do this sort of things with user defined functions. I also know how to go around this problem with gcc options.
I also know that when the program runs the  strcpy breakpoint is resolved. Let me continue.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/reader/booksrc/char_array2
Breakpoint 4 at 0xb7f076f4
Pending breakpoint "strcpy" resolved

Breakpoint 1, main() at char_array2.c:7
7   strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) i r eip
eip 0x80483c4   0x80483c4 <main+16>
(gdb) x/5i $eip
0x80483c4   <main+16>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+4],0x80484c4
0x80483cc   <main+24>:  lea    eax,[ebp-40]
0x80483cf   <main+27>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x80483d2   <main+30>:  call   0x80482c4 <strcpy@plt>
0x80483d7   <main+35>:  lea    eax,[ebp-40]
(gdb) continue
Continuing.


Breakpoint 4, 0xb7f076f4 in strcpy () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb) i r eip
eip    0xb7f076f4    0xb7f076f4 <strcpy+4>
(gdb) x/5i $eip
0xb7f076f4 <strcpy+4>:  mov   esi,DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
0xb7f076f7 <strcpy+7>:  mov   eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
0xb7f076fa <strcpy+10>: mov   ecx,esi
0xb7f076fc <strcpy+12>: sub   ecx,eax
0xb7f076fe <strcpy+14>: mov   edx,eax
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array2.c:8
8
printf(str_a);
(gdb) i r eip
eip    0x80483d7    0x80483d7 <main+35>
(gdb) x/5i $eip
0x80483d7 <main+35>:   lea    eax,[ebp-40]
0x80483da <main+38>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x80483dd <main+41>:   call   0x80482d4 <printf@plt>
0x80483e2 <main+46>:   leave
0x80483e3 <main+47>:   ret
(gdb)
```

This is the second run of the program in which supposedly the address to strcpy is different from the other address.

```
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/reader/booksrc/char_array2
Error in re-setting breakpoint 4:
Function "strcpy" not defined.

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array2.c:7
7
strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) bt
#0 main () at char_array2.c:7
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 4, 0xb7f076f4 in strcpy () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0 0xb7f076f4 in strcpy () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#1 0x080483d7 in main () at char_array2.c:7
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array2.c:8
8
printf(str_a);
(gdb) bt
#0 main () at char_array2.c:8
(gdb)
```

Where is the difference? am I wrong for thinking that  0xb7f076f4 is the address of strcpy? On the second run if I am correct everything indicates that the address is 0xb7f076f4.

Also, what is  ? I can't find the explanation for this anywhere earlier in the book. If someone could be kind enough to explain this from the top down to me I would appreciate it so much being that I don't know any expert in real life that could help me. I find the explanations to be vague, he explains variables and loops like if he was explaining it to a 5 year old, but leaves much of the assembly code for us to figure out by ourselves, I have not been very successful at this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes 0xb7f076f4 is the address of the breakpoint which is in strcpy. What's the question? Having only basic knowledge of assembly and c when I guess trying to understand low-level exploits such as stack overflows just won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: @Voo Not trying to be rude but I did address my confusion in 3 different parts: beginning, middle and ending. I'll ask yet again, the author says that the address of strcpy changes from the first run to the last and I don't see it change from 0xb7f076f4, where is the change? I only see the address of strcpy appear as 0xb7f076f4. And I don't know what the last part of your answer means.

Comment: There's no reason to assume that a library will be loaded at a different base address on repeated runs. Considering that this is libc which is very likely the first loaded library one can generally assume that it'll be at the same memory location in repeated runs as long as ASLR is not active (which I'm somewhat surprised it isn't though)

Comment: @Voo I am not assuming anything, this is not my code, this came from a book(as described in the top part of the question) called "Hacking the Art of exploitation" and this is a problem that the author describes. He might have been wrong in that part, which is why I am turning to people with more experience than me.

Comment: Hey Alex_adl04, if you want to practise exploitation id recommend you to check out the wargames at http://overthewire.org and http://smashthestack.org. also, there is a lot of really good support on the IRC in #wargames.

Comment: @mofoe I will definitely check those out. I have never applied what little I know of programming to anything, I imagined that penetration testing would be a fun concept. I am liking it but sometimes it feels like getting to magic/illusions where good magicians don't show their best tricks

Comment: Ah, don't worry. most people like to share there work and techniques. like in ctfs, there are always high quality writeups published.

Comment: This one really tripped me up. So the two addresses really are the same in the example? I thought I might be losing my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `gdb` turns off [ASLR](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization) for the debugged process to make (session-to-session) debugging easier.

From https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html

```
set disable-randomization
set disable-randomization on
    This option (enabled by default in GDB) will turn off the native 
    randomization of the virtual address space of the started program. 
    This option is useful for multiple debugging sessions to make the 
    execution better reproducible and memory addresses reusable across
    debugging sessions.
```

Set `set disable-randomization off` in `gdb` or in a `.gdbinit` file and try it again. Libc should now get loaded at a different address each time you run the binary.

Running `watch -n 1 cat /proc/self/maps` also is nice to see how the binary and the libraries are mapped at 'random' addresses.

Comment: Great!! I really appreciate this tip. I knew it was going to take quite some time for someone to answer since I imagined that not a lot of people use GDB. Again, thank you mofoe

Answer (score 1):

As @Voo said in his comment above, the book probably refers to ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) which is a security feature. It changes how the address space is used for each execution so you can't rely on finding things always in the same place.

If you don't see it in `gdb` that means you have ASLR turned off. Either globally or locally in `gdb`. You can check the former using `cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` and the latter using `show disable-randomization` command at the `gdb` prompt.